# Lightning:dualListbox Style Not Working As Expected

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, picklist, multi-select, lightning-duallistbox

When I create a `dualListbox` on a lightning component I am unable to see the values. When I inspect I can see that the values are there.

It almost looks like the color is set to white or transparent. But I have tried to change the color with no success.

I have ran a few tests: hardcoding the option values (this worked and I was able to see the values) and I changed the dualListbox to a inputSelect (this worked as well)

What gives? The only thing I can think of is that dualListbox's only support multi-select picklists. I am trying to get tie this to a single select picklist.

[image]

```
<aura:attribute name="leadSourceOptions" type="List"/>
<aura:attribute name="selectedLeadSource" type="List" />

<lightning:card >
        <!--Lead Source-->
        <lightning:dualListbox label= "Lead Source"
                            sourceLabel="Available"
                            selectedLabel="Selected"
                            fieldLevelHelp="This is a dual listbox"
                            options="{!v.leadSourceOptions}"
                            value="{!v.selectedLeadSource}"
                            aura:Id = "leadSourceList"
                            />


loadLeadSourceList: function(component, event) {
    const action = component.get("c.loadLeadSourceList");

    action.setCallback(this, function (response) {
        var state = response.getState();
        if (state === "SUCCESS") {
            var leadData =  response.getReturnValue();
            console.log('source list: ' + leadData);
            component.set("v.leadSourceOptions", leadData); //should return a list of strings of the picklist values 
        } else {
            console.log('Lead Status: ' + state);
        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
},
```

Comment: can you show what exactly did you see for leadData in console log?

Comment: I am creating a custom filter for records and I wanted to display a box of all of the Source options to the user. I wont be making update to the record's picklist. Is there another way to display the box?

Comment: leadData is the source list in the console: `source list: Advertisement,Customer Event,Employee Referral,Google AdWords,Other,Partner,Purchased List,Trade Show,Webinar,Website,Web Forms,Digital,Chat,Inbound ACD OBTM`

Comment: This is just a list of strings. What @gNerb written in answer is correct - it should be List of objects with label and value properties

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your comment says you are trying to use a list of strings.

The reason you're not seeing any values is because you should be using objects that contain a value and a label property which your strings do not contain.

```
if (state === "SUCCESS") {
    var leadData =  response.getReturnValue();
    var selectOptions = [];

    leadData.forEach(function(item){
        selectOptions.push({value:item, label:item});
    }, this);


    component.set("v.leadSourceOptions", selectOptions); //should return a list of strings of the picklist values 
} else {
    console.log('Lead Status: ' + state);
}
```

[Here is the documentation for the component](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:dualListbox/example). It shows something similar.

Comment: thank you, that was it. I needed to have the value and label